# Bootstrap Dropdown Hover Not Working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu in my Rails app that (ideally) should display when you hover the parent `li`.  However, the CSS-only approach I am using doesn't seem to be working for my HTML, though I can't see why.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lizbayardelle/pen/qXxQoz?editors=1100) illustrating the problem.

Here's the HTML/ERB menu:

```
<div id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <%= image_tag "logo_simple.png", alt: "Family Zone Logo" %>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <% if current_user %>
                        <h2>
                            <span class="color-red font-hand"><%= current_user.last_name %></span>
                            <span class="color-blue font-hand">Zone</span>
                        </h2>
                    <% else %>
                        <h2>
                            <span class="color-red font-hand">Family</span>
                            <span class="color-blue font-hand">Zone</span>
                        </h2>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "To Do", tasks_path %></li>
                <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "Scheduling", blogs_path %></li>
                <li class="hvr-grow" id="dropdown-li"><%= link_to 'Tools', home_tools_path, { :class => 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown', 'aria-haspopup' => true, 'aria-expanded' => false, 'role' => "button" } %></li>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><%= link_to "Grocery List", groceries_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Meal Planning", mealplans_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Recipe Box", recipes_path %></li>
                  </ul>
                <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "Research", blogs_path %></li>
                <% if current_user %>
                    <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "Me", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <% else %>
                    <li class="hvr-grow"><%= link_to "Family Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- collapse -->
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- main-nav -->
```

And here's my current CSS:

```
#main-nav.navbar-default a.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px;
    z-index: 30;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default {
    background-color: $transparent-white;
    border: none;
    height: 80px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: $grey;
    font-family: $font-hand;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: $red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    border-bottom: $grey solid thin;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 20px;
  border-color: $red;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: $red;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    border-color: $blue;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: $blue;
}

#main-nav .dropdown-menu:li {
    text-align: left;
}

#main-nav #dropdown-li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
 }
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working or get the codepen to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my updated answer, If its not working please clarify me what behaviour you want,

[image]

```css
#main-nav.navbar-default a.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px;
    z-index: 30;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default {
    background-color: $transparent-white;
    border: none;
    height: 80px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default img {
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default h1 {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: $grey;
    font-family: $font-hand;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
 text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: $red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    border-bottom: $grey solid thin;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 margin-top: 20px;
  border-color: $red;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: $red;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
 border-color: $blue;
}

#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#main-nav.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: $blue;
}

#main-nav .dropdown-menu:li {
    text-align: left;
}

#main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#">Bootstrap theme</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#">Another action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even with this change it doesn't show up.  Also, the original click functionality of the "tools" `li` no longer works.

Comment: I'm checking .. its working .. Please wait i'm try to make a snippet after that we talk about it.

Comment: This works perfectly except for, for some reason, on my code the dropdown disappears when you try to mouse down to the second (or lower) item on the dropdown menu.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu `li` can't close correctly

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>             
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>                
</li>
```

to change this format use above code and include dropdown script also

Comment: I made these changes and it still doesn't show up.  Could it be something to do with the ERB?  Or possibly something elsewhere in my CSS?